# How to take backup of keyspace in cassandra by command?

Tags: cassandra

I want to take the backup of a keyspace in cassandra, Using command.

Comment: The [link](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_backup_restore_c.html) provided by @greg-prisament is the second one in google for `cassandra keyspace backup` search query.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `nodetool` command.  Something like:

```
nodetool -h localhost -p 7199 snapshot mykeyspace
```

Take a look at the documentation here:
http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_backup_restore_c.html